# Laravel Mail why variable with array from database doesn't work?

Tags: php, laravel, email

How can I add an array from the database to my email component in Laravel?

My controller:

```
$request = DB::table('Requests')->where('id', $id)->get();
$email = DB::table('Requests')->where('id', $id)->value('email');

 Mail::to($email)->send(new Order($request));
```

My e-mail component Order:

```
Dear {{ $request->name }}
```

I've read about to add an array with the compact('request') function, but also this didn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please explain what's not working? What's the input and the expected output

Comment: Didn't work how exactly? An error? Unexpected result? What debugging have you done? Please be clear and specific

Answer (score 1):

Your current call using `get()` will return a collection which is maybe your confusion about array.

To reference it in your mailable as it is you would need the first element of the collection (assuming it is found).

```php
Dear {{ $request[0]->name }}
```

Maybe try using `first()` to get a single resource.
E.g.

```php
$request = DB::table('Requests')->where('id', $id)->get()->first();
// or use eloquent
$request = Requests::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
// or if id is the primaray key
$request = Requests::find('id', $id);
```

All the above will get you a single resource.

You can then pass this into your mailable as you were

```php
Mail::to($email)->send(new Order($request));
```

Now you are passing a model object, you can refer to it as you were in your mailable.

```php
Dear {{ $request->name }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've to read about the difference between get and first! It works now!